# How To Determine How I'm Using IP Multicasting?

Tags: ip, multicast

It's my understanding that IP multicasting works by receivers joining IP multicast groups with IGMP messages, senders sending to those addresses, and routers addressed in that way duplicating the message and sending to all receivers in the group.

I've never elected to join a multicast group. What software that I might use would likely join a group on my behalf? Do commonly-used programs often send to multicast addresses on my behalf? What tools, especially command-line tools, expose this information? Something similar to what `ipcs` provides for shared memory, what `ps` provides for processes, etc. I'm especially interested in linux or OSX environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
netstat -g
```

NB there is no duplication. If a router has members inside, it propagates the datagram, once, on the inside LAN.